# From French “manœuvre” to English “manoeuvre”, does “œ” exist in English?

Tags: orthography, loanwords, typography, historical-change, ligature

Sadly, I don’t have much to add from the title to this question: does *œ* exist in English, such as in the word *manœuvre*?

The same question may also apply to what the French call the “e dans l’a” (e in the a), the ***æ***, in addition to what they call the “e dans l’o” (e in the o), the ***œ*** — at least as far as the French part is concerned.

Comment: Wikipedia has a comment "Æ comes from Medieval Latin, where it was an optional ligature in some words, for example, "Æneas". It is still found as a variant in English and French, but the trend has recently been towards printing the A and E separately. Similarly, Œ and œ, while normally printed as ligatures in French, can be replaced by component letters if technical restrictions require it."

Comment: well in french the trend as been to remove all non ascii characters from the charset while printing industry wasn't up to speed. It's not a problem anymore so I hope it won't go on further on this path.

Comment: Does œ exist in English? Yes!

Comment: @Mog œ *is* an ASCII character (156), so it's not a question of removing non-ASCII characters.

Comment: extended ascii. Not quite ascii per-se

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/95?m=4142523#4142523

Comment: @mplungian: I don't know what you're calling medieval, but Æ was used in Old English (called the *ash*) where it was used in words and names abundantly. For example, Æþelræd Unræd (commonly referred to as Ethelred the Unready, which is a mistranslation *and* a mispronunciation). The character was pronounced like the *a* in *ash*, not the *e* in *meth*.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, *œ* is not an ASCII character, nor is there any ASCII characters above 127. For a long time France made use of ISO 8859-1 (Latin 1) but that didn't have a *œ* character either (it did have a *æ* for the Scandinavian languages that have it as a fully separate letter). CP-1252 (Windows Latin 1) does have *œ* at 9C (156 decimal) but it wasn't widely supported on non-Windows machines for quite some time, by which time Unicode made such worries obsolete anyway.

Comment: @Robusto I am quoting Wikipedia.

Comment: ... and while we are at it, shall we go back to spellings like *oeconomics* ??

Comment: @mplungian. Well, that settles it then. Wikipedia is never wrong. Sorry.

Comment: @JonHanna Indeed, this is why they use ISO-8859-15 now, since it has some of those niceties. However, for the most part, everyone has gone over to the UTF-8 encoding of Unicode, leaving all such legacy encodings in the lurch.

Comment: @Robusto [In Old English, *ash*](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/58489/2085) was one of the seven simple vowels: *o, a, æ, e, i, u, y*.  It must be printed as such, because it is a lexical not a typographic ligature, just as it still is in Icelandic.  However, Greek and Latin now usually gets split up, allowing *Æneas* to be written as *Aeneas*, so that he has six letters not five. French is a different matter, though. I’ve written a lot about this in various places.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, be aware that *manoeuvre* is now normally spelled *maneuver* in America, and indeed, has fallen behind *maneuvre* in England. Even the *Economist* (but not the *Œconomist* :) uses *maneuvre* now.

### Rendering Typographic Ligatures Correctly

The general answer is that *œ* is considered a mere **typographic ligature** in written English, not a **lexical ligature** as it is in French.  See [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/55109/2085) for more about all that.

It is the modern custom to print all instances of *œ* as *oe* in English. Indeed, the OED switched its custom from the ligated digraph to the separated form when it went from its 2<sup>nd</sup> to its 3<sup>rd</sup> edition.

Therefore, for example, these words are all now typically printed differently. Notice how in some instances, the *oe* reduces to *e*.  Although increasingly common, that reduction is by no means universal, and does not occur in all words, either.

- amœbæ > amoebae
- apnœa > apnoea, apnea
- cœlacanth > coelacanth
- diarrhœa > diarrhoea, diarrhea
- homœopathic > homoeopathic, homeopathic
- manœuvre > manoeuvre, maneuvre, maneuver
- melopœïa > melopoeia
- Mœbius > Moebius, Möbius, Mobius
- œdema > oedema, edema
- Œdipus > Oedipus
- œnologist > oenologist
- epopœia > epopoeia
- œsophageal > oesophageal, esophageal
- œstrous > oestrus, estrus
- Phœbus Apollo > Phoebus Apollo
- Phœnician > Phoenician
- phœnix > phoenix
- subpœna > subpoena

### Two Exceptions: Lexical Ligatures and the IPA

There are two important exceptions to this.

The first is in terms taken from the French and considered “unassimilated” into English.  These are typically set in italic.  Since *œ* is a lexical not a typographic ligature in French, when printing French terms it is imprescindible that the ligature be maintained.  For example:

- *à contre-cœur*
- *bœuf*
- *casus fœderis*
- *chef d’œuvre*
- *cri de cœur*
- *hors d’œuvre*
- *mœurs*
- *œil-de-bœuf*
- *œuf en cocotte*
- *œufs sur le plat*
- *œuvre*
- *vœu, vœux*

Whether to preserve it in Latin terms like *casus fœderis* or *subpœna* is more controversial. Usually, it is not.

The other important exception is when printing phonetic or phonemic transcriptions in the [International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet).  There are two glyphs that mean something special in IPA, and which **must** be preserved:

- /œ/, the [open mid-front rounded vowel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_front_rounded_vowel)
- /ɶ/, the [open front rounded vowel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_front_rounded_vowel)

### Unicode Considerations

The relevant code points in Unicode are:

```
‭ Œ  0152       LATIN CAPITAL LIGATURE OE
‭ œ  0153       LATIN SMALL LIGATURE OE
        = ethel (from Old English eðel)
        * French, IPA, Old Icelandic, Old English, ...
        x (latin small letter ae - 00E6)
        x (latin letter small capital oe - 0276)
‭ ɶ  0276       LATIN LETTER SMALL CAPITAL OE
        * low front rounded vowel
        x (latin small ligature oe - 0153)
```

Note that these are the **only** code points whose names include the word LIGATURE but which are generally considered lexical not typographical ones.  Unlike the others with LIGATURE in their names, these have no decomposed forms that produce two glyphs, nor are they casewise equivalent to the two-glyph version they are currently spelled with in most English words.  This is because you would get the wrong results under certain conditions if you did so.

These are the other Latin ligatures in Unicode; all are considered typographic in most languages, and have special decomposition and casing rules:

```
‭ Ĳ  0132       LATIN CAPITAL LIGATURE IJ
        # 0049 004A
‭ ĳ  0133       LATIN SMALL LIGATURE IJ
        * Dutch
        # 0069 006A
‭ ﬀ  FB00       LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FF
        # 0066 0066
‭ ﬁ  FB01       LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FI
        # 0066 0069
‭ ﬂ  FB02       LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FL
        # 0066 006C
‭ ﬃ  FB03       LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FFI
        # 0066 0066 0069
‭ ﬄ  FB04       LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FFL
        # 0066 0066 006C
‭ ﬅ  FB05       LATIN SMALL LIGATURE LONG S T
        # 017F 0074
‭ ﬆ  FB06       LATIN SMALL LIGATURE ST
        # 0073 0074
```

Note that all of those are there for legacy round-tripping, and no more such things shall ever be added to Unicode. That is because unlike lexical ligatures, typographic ligatures belong in the font, not the code points.

That is why the typographical ligatures given above get split up under decomposition and caseless matching, but the lexical ligatures do not.

The exception to this is when using the (default, untailored) [Unicode Collation Algorithm (UCA)](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/) for sorting.  Now these code points sort next to the two-glyph version, and count as equivalent at the primary strength (that is, whether they are the same letters or different ones, and without regard to case or diacritics).

Here then is the result of sorting the various words pointed out above using the default UCA:

> à contre-cœur, amoebae, amœbæ, apnea, apnoea, apnœa, bœuf, casus fœderis,
>   chef d’œuvre, coelacanth, cœlacanth, cri de cœur, diarrhea, diarrhoea,
>   diarrhœa, edema, epopoeia, epopœia, esophageal, estrus, homeopathic,
>   homoeopathic, homœopathic, hors d’œuvre, maneuver, maneuvre, manoeuvre,
>   manœuvre, melopoeia, melopœïa, Mobius, Möbius, Moebius, Mœbius, mœurs,
>   oedema, œdema, Oedipus, Œdipus, œil-de-bœuf, oenologist, œnologist,
>   oesophageal, œsophageal, œstrous, oestrus, œuf en cocotte, œufs sur le
>   plat, œuvre, Phoebus Apollo, Phœbus Apollo, Phoenician, Phœnician, phoenix,
>   phœnix, subpoena, subpœna, vœu, vœux.

Comment: How did “Mœbius” land on that list? That spelling is quite puzzling since the Möbius strip (that is probably referred to here) is named after German mathematician Möbius whose name’s spelling I’ve never seen written differently, and proper names usually have no legitimate alternative spellings (bar transliterations).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Isn’t that weird? It is in the OED2.

Comment: That doesn’t make it less weird in my perception. Proper names are one of the few (the only?) cases where something akin to a canonical spelling exists. For instance, no matter how many people will write about “Shrodinger’s cat”, that spelling is *wrong*. It surprises me that this isn’t the case here (but then the name is much older).

Comment: @KonradRudolph, not only that, but "œ" maps to a different pronunciation. In "Mœbius" it maps to an "oh" sound and all the other forms to an "ee" sound. Did the OED make a mistake here? (Note the OED is not to be confused with the ŒD)

Comment: @Ben Not really: “ö” in German ([/ø/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-mid_front_rounded_vowel)) maps to the exactly same sound as “œ” in French (although in French it may also be open: [/œ/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_front_rounded_vowel), compare French “vœux” (closed) and “cœur” (open)) and corresponds closely to the “i” in “bird”. The other words are similarly pronounced in varying fashions – it’s just that the closed form (ø) doesn’t have a very good correspondence in most English accents so the words are distorted accordingly.

Comment: Could it be because of the notion that "typographical ligatures belong in the font"? Fonts generally don't have a vocabulary in order to decide when to use ligatures. Human typesetters did have a vocabulary, but wouldn't necessarily think a word like "Moebius" should be treated specially if the general rule is that ligatures are typographical. One possible consequence of this notion is that *all* instances of "oe" in English typesetting could be rendered "œ", regardless of how they were produced including from German "ö". It's just hyper-active kerning ;-)

Comment: (Moebius being a standard transliteration of Möbius, just as Gauss is of Gauß).

Answer (score 12):

It's not unheard of to see *Œ* in English orthography, and was once much more common than it is now. These days though, it would be so rare as to be only barely acceptable, unless the word was clearly being used as a foreign word (e.g. with italics). (I personally use it privately, but I'll change it in anything being sent to an editor even if I'm not writing to a particular style-guide).

Generally British English spellings change it to *oe* (*manoeuvre*, *foetus*) while American spellings change it to *e* (*maneuvre*, *fetus*), this being one of Noah Webster's reforms. This can't be depended upon: *Foederal* is almost never found anywhere (any later than the 18th Century or so, anyway), and conversely while *subpena* is found in American spellings, *sub poena* is more common there.

*Æ* is mostly similar, though note that the existance of *Æ* in a modern word can be from two sources - one is from ligatures the same as with *Œ*, while the other is a separate vowel letter independent of *A* and *E* that was once used in Old English and is still used in Danish, Norwegian, Faroese and Icelandic (In Swedish and German it mutated into *Ä*). If a word is borrowed from one of those languages, but changed to use the English alphabet, then it would be common to see its spelling become *ae* rather than *e* even in American spellings.

One place ligatures remain in modern English is the name *Encyclopædia Britannica*, since that's the way they spell it, and trademarks and personal and company names are not normally re-spelled between different English orthographies.

Comment: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=+man%C5%93uvre%2C+manoeuvre&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=

Comment: @mplungjan http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=man%C5%93uvre%2Cmanoeuvre&year_start=1760&year_end=1800&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share= But yes, there's a reason why even though I use it myself, I edit it to en-GB orthography (or sometimes en-GB-oed since one of my editors so loves it, that he's the guy that registered en-GB-oed). It's *very* rare unless as a foreign-use. Likewise I personally use diærses in a way that no publication bar The New Yorker uses, so I edit them to something else if it's for publication.

Comment: Note that the OED calls the *fetus* spelling “etymologically preferable”.  The *foetus* (mis-)spelling was an old error that got retransmitted. Sadly.

Comment: @tchrist Seriously? In Dutch it is written and pronounced foetus

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, quite seriously.

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, it's an interesting case of hyper-correction. The Latin is *fetus*, but some people in the 16th Century that knew (or correctly guessed) it was from Latin got it into their heads that it should have been *foetus* / *fœtus* in the Latin, and "fixed" the spelling not just in Latin, but also in English, Dutch and German (in which *fetus*, *foetus* and *fötus* are all found). For extra fun, the modern en-US *fetus* **might** be a simplification of the hyper-correction that just arrived at the original by chance.

Comment: Are you quite sure? The only “American” spelling of *poena > pena* I have ever seen is in the Spanish “so pena de muerte” and such.  [Writs of subpoena](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpoena) are always spelled that way. I am pretty sure that *subpena* would be considered an error.

Comment: @tchrist some time before when I was going to use it as an example that is only spelt *subpoena* or *sub poena* in en-US, I found that there are indeed several cases of *subpena* in the US Code. Of course it's possible that you may think that some of your legislators shouldn't be used as an example of the spellings used by reasonably educated users of the language! ;)

Comment: I was also thinking of the Encyclopædia Britannica. Another use that's still comparatively common AFAIK is that in "curriculum vitæ". Perhaps because there's an increased incentive to show off ;) OTOH that's exactly the reason why I wouldn't use this in a CV itself – it easily comes off as presumptuous.

Comment: "Mediæval" isn't all that uncommon in British English either. I speculate because the word itself inclines some people to prefer an old-looking spelling.

Answer (score 5):

The ligatures can certainly be found in English, although their use is becoming less common — probably due to the rise in personal computers and the difficulty in using ligatures with a standard keyboard.

OED gives a recent citation showing the ligature:

> 1977   *Lancet* 28 May 1140/1: “In shallow diving an over-forceful Valsalva manœuvre may give rise to neuro-sensory hearing loss, with or without vertigo.”

Their citations after 1977 all have separate letters.

Comment: Difficulty with the standard keyboard? Not at all. Press option-q or option-' on the Mac keyboard and you will easily obtain the œ and the æ, respectively.

Comment: I think the comment about *difficulty in using ligatures with a standard keyboard* was aimed directly at lazy Microsoft Windows OS users who can't be bothered to find out about their keyboard characters :) Those of us on Macintosh have never had this problem.