# List of characters with diacritics accepted in English words

Tags: contemporary-english, alphabet, diacritics

Some diacritics and special characters (like ligatures) are **accepted** in Contemporary English: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_terms_with_diacritical_marks

Examples of English spellings: coöperative, reëlect, naïve, soupçon, frappé, piñata, Geiger–Müller, Wilhelm Röntgen, László Bíró, …

Some others **aren't accepted** and wouldn't be used in any publication for an English spelling.

Examples of characters never used in English words: ⱥ, Ω, あ, …

**What are the lists of characters with diacritics or special characters (like ligatures) accepted in Contemporary English words?**

Question is narrowed to reference organisms or major publications, as:

- Dictionaries
- Universities, Academic publications
- Newspapers

Question does not include:

- anything non-Contemporary, i.e. older than October 6, 1960 (American Standards Association's first meeting to create ASCII)
- non Latin/Roman characters, as you would perform [romanization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization) on it to make it an English spelling
- symbols ([Ƭ̵̬̊](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%C6%AC%CC%B5%CC%AC%CC%8A&redirect=no)) or emojis (, Oxford Dictionaries 2015 Word of the year)
- fiction publications, blogs

Example possible partial list of accepted characters based on Wikipedia article above, would be (in lowercase mostly): äëïöüáóíéèàìôēāăŏčšřžåçșñďľňťŁđćĦ

Comment: It depends on the publisher. There is no official list, as there is no single definition of standard English.

Comment: Related: [Diacriticals and non-English letters in anglicized loan words: keep 'em, dump 'em, italicize the words, or what?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13343)

Comment: You don't get to pick and choose how to write somebody else’s name. If it’s written in the thing we have come to call the Latin alphabet, then you have to write it the way they tell you to. It doesn’t matter if it as letters we don't use in English. If you don’t believe me, then  Hafþór Júlíus Björnsson might care to have a word with you. Please see [this related question](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/80397/2085), especially the excerpt from Bringhurst.

Comment: @tchrist, thanks for agreeing with the examples of the question (where you can see the example of László Bíró). I was hoping to find a list of those characters.

Comment: @tchrist: That's just one opinion. There really is nobody who has the authority to dictate a rule for everyone who writes in English. And the rule you mention is not generally followed by English language publications. For example, [the *Economist* only includes diacritics that are used in certain common European languages; others get dropped](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=27213). (Apparently, the reason is that they use a [bespoke typeface](http://languagehat.com/greek-in-the-times/) and they don't want to pay for the design of characters that will be rarely used.)

Comment: @suməlic I will take Bringhurt’s opinion on matters typographical over a newspaper editor's. That said, I actually telephoned said editor at the *Economist* a few years ago and lobbied to get them to update their policy from only respecting French and German names in this regard and stop disrespecting Spanish and Portuguese names. They agreed with me, and did so.

Comment: @tchrist: Well, the Language Log article about the spelling of Erdoğan is from August of this year. The *Economist* evidently added Portuguese diacritics, but they still don't seem to have full coverage of the Latin alphabet. Bringhurst's opinion is certainly deserving of respect, but unfortunately I don't think it can be said to be a "standard". There isn't any established standard.

Comment: Aren't you actually asking about computer compatibility?

Comment: This is arbitrary and differs according to domain. For instance, though you say 'Examples of characters never used in English: ⱥ, Ω, ...',  Ω is often used in English science textbooks. Also, an illustation could contain _any_ symbol.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts to edit this question to make it more answerable. It still seems quite broad to me. Can you narrow the scope any further by specifying any classes of publications that you are interested in? For example, do you want to know about the practices of major newspaper and magazine publishers, or the practices followed by academic journals, or the practices followed in fiction, or in non-fiction books?

Comment: I counsel you to please, please read—and then reread very carefully—what all Robert Bringhurst says about **current Latin’s *600-character* alphabet** and Unicode’s 100.000-character alphabet, including this: [***Yet authors, editors, typographers, and ordinary citizens who just want to be able to spell Dvořák, Miłosz, Mą’ii, or al‐Fārābī, or to quote a line of Sophocles or Pushkin, or the Vedas or the Sutras or the Psalms, or to write φ ≠ π, are beneficiaries of a system this inclusive.***](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/80397) And I do hope you see what I’ve just done there. :)

Comment: @suməlic. As a non-native English speaker, I now understand that there is no top reference for English spelling (as opposed to some other languages like my native one where we have *Académie française* and *Office québécois de la langue française* to answer this directly). So, as requested, unintentional broad scope is now narrowed down.

Comment: @tchrist, I think it's worth to put Robert Bringhurst's opinion as an answer instead of just a comment.

Comment: @Cœur I agree with you, and if the community chooses to reöpen your question, then I shall surely do so.