# In English, are apostrophes supposed to be a ‹ ’ › or ‹ ‘ › or ‹ ‛› or ‹ ' › — or are those all the same so it doesn’t matter?

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives, apostrophe, quotation-marks, greengrocers-apostrophe

> Let us pray for our
>   husbands‘ long lives.

[image]

The `‘` quote is really weird here. I usually use `'` in those situations, was I wrong? How do you even type that?

Comment: That does indeed seem to be a typographical error. Personally I would type that character with the key right under my `esc` key, I guess.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a bout a simply typo, not about English language and usage.

Comment: @oerkelens Do you think the edited title question is still ***not*** about English? The question body seemed unclear what an English apostrophe should even “be”.

Comment: Are they getting reputation for closing questions? Because people on these sites really like doing that for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Just a bit oﬀ: *2019 − 2018 = 1*

If this were text you found on the Internet, particularly on the Web, then because [more than 90% of websites worldwide use Unicode](https://w3techs.com/technologies/details/en-utf8/all/all) text, we would be able to examine the actual codes used for that bit of text and so give you a very good guess as to what has gone wrong.

<s>However, here we cannot be so sure of this because you have shown only an image full of pixels instead of a bit of computer text whose values we could analyse.   That’s because diﬀerent characters can look very similar and sometimes even identical to each other, especially when you take into account the choice of typeface (as in font) used for displaying the glyphs.</s>

UPDATE: I missed the topmost line, in which the coded character is indeed a **LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK**, character number 2018. The direction is reversed compared with how we write an apostrophe in English, which should be character 2018, **RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK**.

Details follow.

---

Furthermore, you cannot trust “helpful” software not to change which character you’ve used right out from under you no matter what you’ve yourself just used.

The most likely explanation is that the person entering the original text made an oﬀ-by-one error when they entered that line of text. They probably used Unicode character U+2018 `LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK` when they should have instead used Unicode character U+2019 `RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK`.

This isn’t a mistake that’s likely to be seen by people writing out text in longhand with pen and paper. Neither do you expect professional typesetters to make so glaring an error, because they always understood the stark diﬀerence between one and the other form:

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/ClavierLinotype_20041006-163300.jpg]

<sup><sub>Credit: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/ClavierLinotype_20041006-163300.jpg</sub></sup>

Typesetters don’t use keyboards like that any longer, but they do still have special keyboard mappings to enter the precisely desired character. However, whoever entered that text was unlikely to have been a professional typesetter, so they were stuck with whatever the labels on the keys of their little computer typewriter keyboard, which never has any keys labelled with those characters that are actually needed. So some allowance has to be made for non-professional text entry when no one wants to hire a professional for “such a simple job” any longer.

Because of the deceptively unhelpful practices of [WYSIWYG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) text-entry software that attempts to impose magical transformations like “smart quotes” on what you enter, what you type is quite often **NOT** what you get — and neither is what you see.

So probably what happened is that somebody used an old-fashioned computer typewriter that had only a single key with a “straight single quote” on it, something that was in most ways no more sophisticated than your average vintage typewriter had for its keycaps:

[image: http://www.vintagetypewritershoppe.com/i/TYPEWRITERS2222/P5031207.JPG]
 
<sup><sub>Credit: http://www.vintagetypewritershoppe.com/i/TYPEWRITERS2222/P5031207.JPG</sub></sup>

That means the keystroke they entered probably recorded the legacy character found at Unicode U+0027 `APOSTROPHE`. That character is supported for interacting with legacy text, but it is not what should be used going forward. That’s because the [Unicode Character Database](http://unicode.org/ucd/) specifically notes of that old ASCII apostrophe code point that: (*bold emphasis mine*)

> - neutral (vertical) glyph with mixed usage
> - *2019 is preferred for apostrophe*
> - preferred characters in English for paired quotation marks are 2018 & 2019

As I earlier mentioned, they *should* have use U+2019 for that apostrophe, but for whatever reason of fumbled fingers or broken smart-quote algorithms (read: *smarty-pants* algorithms) from What You See **Ain’t** What You Get layman’s text-entry software, they got U+2018 instead. Those two numbers diﬀer only in their [least significant bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_significant_bit), so it’s always possible that cosmic rays or Grace Hopper’s electrocuted insect toggled a bit the wrong way. But it’s probably use user error.

### [FMTEYEWTK](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/Far+More+Than+You+Ever+Wanted+to+Know) about Apostrophic Lookalikes in Unicode

To say that Unicode has “a lot of characters” is an injustice to the *“a lot of”* premodifying quantifier phrase. Unicode has well over [a hundred thousand characters](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/80397/2085), and it’s constantly growing.

To simplify things, here are a couple dozen Unicode characters that can be confused for apostrophes and their kin. Some actually **are** apostrophes; others look like apostrophes but aren’t; some aren’t called apostrophes but are. Number 1 on the list is probably what they entered but should not have. They should have entered number 14 on the list but they somehow ended up with number 13 instead.

#### Key to Table

To understand this listing, the `U+*NNNN*` entry is the Unicode code point, the number that identifies the character. The **BOLD NAME** is the oﬃcial name, and the italicized list on the next line following is the various diﬀerent character “properties” that apply to that code point. Notice that some are letters, some are punctuation, and some are symbols. But only two are ASCII, and most people don’t know how to enter anything but ASCII on their legacy keyboards.

1. `U+0027` ‹'› **APOSTROPHE** 
   *ASCII, Punctuation, Other Punctuation, Quotation Mark*
2. `U+0060` ‹`› **GRAVE ACCENT** 
   *ASCII, Symbol, Modifier Symbol, Diacritic*
3. `U+00B4` ‹´› **ACUTE ACCENT** 
   *In Block=Latin 1, Symbol, Modifier Symbol, Changes When NFKC Casefolded, Diacritic*
4. `U+02B9` ‹ʹ› **MODIFIER LETTER PRIME** 
   *Alphabetic, Letter, Modifier Letter, Diacritic*
5. `U+02BB` ‹ʻ› **MODIFIER LETTER TURNED COMMA** 
   *Letter, Modifier Letter, Spacing Modifier Letters, Diacritic*
6. `U+02BC` ‹ʼ› **MODIFIER LETTER APOSTROPHE** 
   *Letter, Modifier Letter, Spacing Modifier Letters, Diacritic*
7. `U+02BD` ‹ʽ› **MODIFIER LETTER REVERSED COMMA** *Letter, Modifier Letter, Spacing Modifier Letters, Diacritic*
8. `U+02C8` ‹ˈ› **MODIFIER LETTER VERTICAL LINE** 
   *Letter, Modifier Letter, Spacing Modifier Letters*
9. `U+02CA` ‹ˊ› **MODIFIER LETTER ACUTE ACCENT** 
   *Letter, Modifier Letter, Spacing Modifier Letters, Diacritic*
10. `U+02CB` ‹ˋ› **MODIFIER LETTER GRAVE ACCENT** 
    *Letter, Modifier Letter, Spacing Modifier Letters, Diacritic*
11. `U+0300` ‹◌̀› **COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT** 
    *Mark, Nonspacing Mark, Combining Diacritical Marks, Diacritic*
12. `U+0301` ‹◌́› **COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT** 
    *Mark, Nonspacing Mark, Combining Diacritical Marks, Diacritic*
13. `U+2018` ‹‘› **LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK** 
    *Punctuation, Initial Punctuation, Quotation Mark*
14. `U+2019` ‹’› **RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK** 
    *Punctuation, Final Punctuation, Quotation Mark*
15. `U+201B` ‹‛› **SINGLE HIGH-REVERSED-9 QUOTATION MARK** 
    *Punctuation, Initial Punctuation, Quotation Mark*
16. `U+2032` ‹′› **PRIME** 
    *Punctuation, Other Punctuation, Math*
17. `U+2035` ‹‵› **REVERSED PRIME** 
    *Punctuation, Other Punctuation*
18. `U+275B` ‹❛› **HEAVY SINGLE TURNED COMMA QUOTATION MARK ORNAMENT** 
    *Symbol, Other Symbol, Dingbats*
19. `U+275C` ‹❜› **HEAVY SINGLE COMMA QUOTATION MARK ORNAMENT** 
    *Symbol, Other Symbol, Dingbats*
20. `U+A78C` ‹ꞌ› **LATIN SMALL LETTER SALTILLO** 
    *Is Script=Latin, Letter, Cased Letter, Lowercase Letter, Lowercase*
21. `U+FF07` ‹＇› **FULLWIDTH APOSTROPHE** 
    *Punctuation, Other Punctuation, Changes When NFKC Casefolded, Quotation Mark*
22. `U+FF40` ‹｀› **FULLWIDTH GRAVE ACCENT** 
    *Symbol, Modifier Symbol, Changes When NFKC Casefolded, Diacritic*

For those using a Mac keyboard, you can enter the correct U+2019 character by using the `SHIFT + ALT + ]` keystroke combination.

Comment: "you have shown only an image full of pixels instead of a bit of computer text whose values we could analyse" Um, I copypasted it from the subtitles file, it's the very first line.

Comment: @puppon-su My apologies for having overlooked that. I shall amend my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like typo mistake. It should be apostrophe and sentence should be like

> Let us pray for our husband's long lives.

Backquote is not fitted in this sentence.

Comment: It can actually be _Let us pray for our husbands' long lives._ as well, making the mistake indeed a pure typo and not even a grammatical mistake.

Comment: This answer would only work for one shared husband with many lives. The apostrophe should be after the *s*

Comment: Context: it is sung by a group of girls. So, husbands' is probably correct.

Comment: Please edit your posting to fix the grammar: one cannot say "is not fitted" to mean "does not fit".