# What is the character set of the (written) English language?

Tags: writing, historical-change, symbols

More specifically:

What dictionaries or lexicons (considering all ever published) of the English language contain exhaustive lists of the characters or symbols used in the formation of the words contained therein? In a modern dictionary, such a list would contain a-z, the apostrophe, and the hyphen. I would not count special symbols that are used only in guiding pronunciation.

This is not a question about typography, but a similar question must come up every time someone designs a typeface (whether produced physically or electronically).

Comment: I'm glad you want to participate, but you're asking too many questions at once. Try to limit your query to something more specific. The [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) has a lot of good advice for asking questions.

Comment: It's English -- there are no "rules", no single "authority".  The character set is whatever the typesetter can accomplish.

Comment: When you design a new typeface today, you generally design it so they can typeset German, French, Spanish, Italian, Swedish, in it. And that still isn't enough letters for Hungarian, Turkish, Romanian,  Polish, Croatian, and other languages. So I really don't think it's come up every time somebody designed a new typeface.

Comment: And this character set has definitely changed over time. 200 years ago, there were just hyphens and dashes. We now have hyphens, en-dashes, and em-dashes.

Comment: @HotLicks, English has rules. Otherwise, you would not be able to read this response. The rules are fluid, which is why I included the concept of change over time, and they are not strict. But this is not the same as a lack of rules.

Comment: @PeterShor. By "just," I suppose you are restricting your comment to dash-like symbols?

Comment: @Ana: correct – we have three dash-like symbols now—short, medium, and long; whereas in the 19th century, printers just used two lengths of dash-like symbols, short and long.

Comment: @PeterShor, indeed. I have a copy of _The Century Collegiate Handbook_ (3rd ed. Greever, Jones, and Jones; Appleton-Century-Crofts; 1952). Therein, they recognize _the_ dash (not several kinds): "Use a single dash to denote hesitancy or breaking off. Use dashes in pairs to set off interrupters... Make the dash twice as long as the hyphen."

Comment: [Very strongly related](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/80397/2085). “The fact that such a character set was long considered adequate tells us something about the cultural narrowness of American civilization, or American technocracy, in the midst of twentieth century.” —Bringhurst

Comment: These are English words **per the OED**: *Allerød, fête, Niçoise, smørrebrød,
après-ski, feuilleté, piñon, soirée,
Bokmål, flügelhorn, plaçage, tapénade,
brassière, Gödelian, prêt-à-porter, vicuña,
caña, jalapeño, Provençal, vis-à-vis,
crème, Madrileño, quinceañera, Zuñi,
crêpe, Möbius, Ragnarök, α-ketoisovaleric acid,
désoeuvrement, Mohorovičić discontinuity, résumé, (α-)lipoic acid,
Fabergé, moiré, Schrödinger, (β-)nornicotine,
façade, naïve, Shijō, ψ-ionone.*

Comment: The alphabet, numerals and symbols. Symbols are part of typography, not language. A period, a comma, an exclamation mark, are not "owned" by the English language, though presumed to be part of the writing by convention. It's not right to say that they are English language symbols. I had great difficulty in convincing my printer that the symbol for *pi* is an essential part of his inventory even though he is an exclusively English language printer.

Comment: @tchrist No one has control over borrowed words. If I say Myötähäpeä and it catches up, OED someday will gladly include it.

Comment: The Q is not about the English language and Usage.

Comment: @Kris: I think it's pretty clearly about English language and usage. It may be unanswerable, though, because it's not really specific enough about what it wants.

Comment: @AnaNimbus - Depends on who you ask.  When the "experts" often don't agree with each other, and what is considered "correct" can vary from one society to another, what you are talking about is closer to "guidelines" than "rules".

Comment: I don't think requests for resources are on topic here. It might be on topic on Meta. Please check this [Meta post](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10583/what-sort-of-resource-request-questions-do-we-accept-on-meta).

Comment: @PeterShor There's a previous comment by me providing the basis for my later comment.