# When do I use æ?

Tags: orthography, old-english

I've always seen this letter but didn't start learning about it until 10 minutes ago. What I was wondering most was when to use it. I have found some conflicting sources about it so if anyone could give me a straight answer that would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you ask me, *never*. It's no more appropriate in English today than the [thorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_(letter)) character (leading people today to actually *articulate* things antiquated signs like ***Ye** Olde Curiosity Shoppe* with a ***Y*** instead of a ***TH***).

Comment: Related: [Is the word “formulæ” valid English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41321/is-the-word-formul%C3%A6-valid-english)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Note he said Old English, not now. Just like Modern Icelandic, in OE it was a distinct letter, not just a fussy ligature that doesn't matter.

Comment: @tchrist: What I notice is that he said *When **do** I use it?*, not *When **did** [our ancestors] use it?* Some people might think it's not as antiquated as the thorn, but it's still *way* past it's sell-by date.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Bear in mind that the word "the" was never pronounced "ye". It was simply that at one time the "th" sound was represented by a character that looked like a Y. So any  "Ye Olde Tea Shoppe" is simply "the old tea shop" - very boring.

Comment: @WS2: You kinow that, and I know that. But I'd be prepared to bet there are millions of Brits who *don't* - and consequently assume that their Anglophone ancestors did in fact say ***ye*** for ***the***. It's not totally ridiculous though, when you consider that many casual / dialectal speakers today use (unstressed) ***yer = your*** instead of unstressed ***the*** (both with just a neutral schwa for the vowel). *Ya take yer square peg and ya **ram** it into yer round hole!*

Comment: @FumbleFingers The tag says **OLD ENGLISH**. It is a separate letter in that language, just as it is in Icelandic. Don't make me send you one of Tolkien's original works he composed in Old English. :)

Comment: Only if you're writing for *The New Yorker*.

Comment: Please add a bit more explanation of the context for this question. What are the "conflicting sources" that you found, and what do they say? Why does this question have the tag "old-english"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yer pays yer money and yer takes yer choice!

Answer (score 1):

It is an ancient  grapheme sometimes used in literary/historical contexts. I don’t think you will need to use it in current common language.

> ***[Æ](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%86) (minuscule: æ***) is a grapheme named æsc or ash,***  formed from the letters a and e, originally a ligature representing the Latin diphthong ae.
>
> In English æ is often eschewed in favour of the digraph ae. Usage experts often consider that incorrect, especially for foreign words in which æ is considered a letter (such as Æsir, Ærø) or brand names that use the ligature or a variation of it (such as Æon Flux, Encyclopædia Britannica, Ætna, Inc.).
>
> Given their long history, ligatures are sometimes used to invoke archaism or in literal quotations of historic sources; for instance, words such as dæmon or æther are often treated so.

(Wikipedia)

Comment: In English phonology as in phonetics, the symbol **æ** is used to denote the sound of the low front vowel in _ash, lap, bad, Sam,_ and _mass_. That's not "short A" -- that's what it was in Middle English, all right, but this is Modern English, and it's  just /æ/.

Comment: @JohnLawler Oxford Dictionary have in later years preferred IPA /a/ (open front unrounded vowel) instead of IPA /æ/ (near-open front unrounded vowel) for this sound. I notice many dictionaries still prescribe /æ/ for this sound, though.

Comment: Some dictionaries have different lexicographers. Most Americans, for instance, pronounce _am_ like I do,  as /ɛm/ instead of either /æ/ or /a/.